# How to convert String to CLLocation?

Tags: swift3

String ->  ["Location: < 37.78583400,-122.40641700>  /- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 5/8/17, 10:26:50 PM Pacific Daylight Time"]

to CLLocation

Comment: You need to extract the two numeric values between the angle brackets with `NSScanner` or Regular Expression, create `Double`s then pass them to a  `CLLocation` initializer. Btw: it looks more like a string in an array.

Comment: Yep, it looks like you converted `CLLocation` to string by something like "Location: \(location)" and stored this in an array. Consider revisiting that code and using Dictionary or something else to avoid converting location to string and reading this string back. Or tell us more about your situation

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this:

```
import CoreLocation
let String = "Location: < 37.78583400,-122.40641700> /- 5.00m (speed 
    -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 5/8/17, 10:26:50 PM Pacific Daylight 
    Time"

let latLongString = String.components(separatedBy: "< ")[1].components(separatedBy: ">")[0]

let lat = latLongString.components(separatedBy: ",")[0]
let long = latLongString.components(separatedBy: ",")[1]


if let latitude =  Double(lat), let longitude = Double(long) {
let coordinate:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

}
```